# How to run a Jest test on an element only if it exists

Tags: javascript, reactjs, testing, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have a simple Jest / React Testing Library line like this...

```
expect(getByTestId('my-elem')).toHaveTextContent('hello');
```

In some cases `my-elem` will not exist (which is a valid case) and in that case I want either a) this test does not run or b) the test passes. Either is fine.

Is this possible?

I essentially want this, but as far as I can tell this isn't possible.

```
if (getByTestId('my-elem').exists()) {
  expect(getByTestId('my-elem')).toHaveTextContent('hello');
}
```

Edit: my case was that this element was available in some situations not available in others. One quick fix was - rather than not rendering the element, making it `visible: hidden` when it should not be available. This fixes things.

Comment: That's a clear signal of mixed responsibilities in your components. You should be able to write two different tests in this case. You can't (and shouldn't) say "Hey test case, don't run for these situations". I'd refactor the structure of that component

Comment: So our app allows people to create modules, then come back and edit them. Some have certain functionality, and some don't (that's config-driven based on module type). This test is to test that they load correctly and it's important to check that if a module is supposed to have a certain thing, it's displayed correctly in the UI. So it's a valid case to have it in the UI or not. I'm not sure how I'd work around that.
So we're loading a bunch of test modules to verify, some will have this in the UI and some won't. I'd rather not duplicate an entire test suite just for this case.

Comment: See my edit. I'll just make the element invisible in those cases, rather than not rendering it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.

```
expect(getByTestId('my-elem')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

Comment: But that doesn't solve my issue. I want to say "If it's in the document, check that it has a certain value. If it's not in the document, it's fine, pass or skip this test".

Comment: Will it render your `my-elem` even if the value is not there? Why would you not want to test non existence of element?

Comment: In our app, users create modules of different types. Some have this functionality and some don't. So depending on the module type, this thing will be there or not.
This test is loading a bunch of modules and testing the UI. In some cases the element will be there and if so, we want to test and make sure it's displaying the correct text. In other cases it's not there and we won't test at all (or just pass the test).

Comment: See my edit. I'll just make the element invisible in those cases, rather than not rendering it.

Comment: Again in my opinion its not correct to skip a test. Your scenario is correct, if that particular element may not exists. But that scenario also needs to be tested. There is a discussion related to this [link](https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/7245). Hope this helps

Comment: Awesome. I'll check out that link. Thanks for the help.